# algorithms to evaluate user responses

Tags: algorithm, statistics, probability, data-mining

I'm working on a web application which will be used for classifying photos of automobiles. The users will be presented with photos of various vehicles, and will be asked to answer a series of questions about what they see. The results will be recorded to a database, averaged, and displayed.

I'm looking for algorithms to help me identify users which frequently don't vote with the group, indicating that they're probably either not paying attention to the photos, or that they're lying about what they see. I then want to exclude these users, and recalculate the results, such that I can say, with a known amount of confidence, that this particular photo shows a vehicle that is this and that.

This question goes out to all you computer science guys, where to find such algorithms or to give myself the theoretical background to design such algorithms. I'm assuming I'm going to have to learn some probability and statics, maybe some data mining. Some book recommendations would be great. Thanks!

P.S. These are multiple choice questions.

All of these are good suggestions. Thank you! I wish there was a way on stack overflow to select multiple correct answers so more of you could be acknowledged for your contributions!!

Comment: Are the questions open ended or multiple choice? Are they subjective or objective with typically one correct answer?

Comment: they're multiple choice question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you described is solved using [outlier/anomaly detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection).
A number of techniques exist:

- statistical-based methods
- distance-based methods
- model-based methods

I suggest you take a look at these [slides](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~kumar/dmbook/dmslides/chap10_anomaly_detection.ppt) from the excellent book [Introduction to Data Mining](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~kumar/dmbook/index.php)

Answer (score 3):

Read [The Elements of Statistical Learning](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/download.html), it is a great compendium on data mining.

You can be interested especially in unsupervised algorithms, for example clustering. Assuming that most people do not lie, the biggest cluster is right and the rest is wrong. Mark people accordingly, then apply some bayesian statistics and you'll be done.

Of course, most data mining technologies are pretty experimentative, so don't count on that they will be always right... or even in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what answers you are expecting why do you ask people to vote? By excluding some values you basically turn the vote in something that **you** like. Automobiles make different impression to different individuals. If 100 ppl loved a car then when someone comes and says that he/she doesn't like it, you exclude the vote?

But anyway, considering that you still want to do this, first of all you will need a large set o data from "trusted" voters. This will give you an idea of "good" answer and from this point you can choose the exclude threshold.

Without an initial set of data you cannot apply any algorithm because you will get false results. Consider just one vote of 100 from on a scale from 0 to 100. The second vote is "1" The you will exclude this vote because is too far away from the average.

Answer (score 0):

I think a pretty simple algorithm could accomplish this for you.  You could try and get fancier by calculating the standard deviations and such, but I wouldn't bother.

Here's a simple approach that should be sufficient:

For each of your users, calculate the number of questions they answered and the number of times they selected the most popular answer for the question.  The users which have the lowest ratio of picking the popular answer versus total answers you can guess are providing bogus data.

You probably would not want to throw out the data from users where they've only answered a small number of questions because they likely have just disagreed on a few versus putting in bogus data.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of questions are they (Yes/No, or 1 to 10?).

You may be able to get away with not discarding anything by using a mean instead of an average.  With averages if there are extreme outliers in the response it could affect the average, but if you use median you may get a better answer.  So for example if you had 5 answers, order them and pick the middle one.

Comment: A mean is an average. Did you mean to say "median instead of an average"?

Comment: @erickson, yes I meant median, sorry thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are saying is that you are concerned that certain people are "outliers", and they are adding noise to your data, making the categorizations less reliable. So, if you have a Chevy Camaro, and most people say it is either a pony car, a muscle car, or a sports car, but you have some goofball who says it's a family sedan, you would want to minimize the impact of his vote.

One thing you could do is provide a Stack Overflow-like reputation score for users:

- The more a user is "in agreement" with other users, the better his or her score would be. For a given user (User X), this could be determined by a simple calculation of what percentage of users who responded to a question chose the same category as User X, then averaging this value over all questions answered.
- You may want to to multiply this value by the total number of question answered to encourage people to answer as many questions as possible. (Note: if you choose to do this, it would be equivalent to just summing the percentage agreement scores rather than averaging them.)
- You could present the final reputation score to users, making sure to explain that they will be rewarded for how well their responses agree with those of other users. This will encourage people to answer more questions but also to take care in their answers.
- Finally, you could calculate a certainty score for a given categorization by adding up the total reputation score of all people who chose a given category.

Some of these ideas may need some refinement, especially since I don't know your exact situation. Certainly, if people can see what other people chose *before* they vote, it would be way too easy to game the system.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to collect votes like "on a scale from 1 to 10, how would you rate this car", you could probably use simple average and standard deviation: the smaller the standard deviation, the more unanimous the general consensus is among your voters, and you can flag users who are e.g. 3 standard devs from the average.

For multiple choice, you need to be more careful. Simply discarding all but the most-voted option will do nothing but disgruntle the voters. You need to establish a measure of how significant the winner is w.r.t. the other options, e.g. flag users who voted for options with less than 1/3 of the winning options count.

Note that I wrote "flag users", *not* discard votes. If you discard votes, you can't tell how confident you are about the result ("91% voted this to be a Ford Mustang"). If a user has more than a certain percentage of his votes flagged - well, that's up to you.

Your trickiest problem, however, will probably be to collect sufficient votes. Depending on how easy the multiple choice problem is, you probably need several times the number of options as votes, per photo. Otherwise the statistics are meaningless.